# Calculate first day of week as a special result string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a special request for a new project. We've got a date like "2022-02-01" and we have to calculate it to get the following string as result "WB - Jan-31". It has to be always the date of the first day of the week. First day of week is Monday. A colleague give the hint to solve it with the to_char () function, but how do I manage to get a result like this?

| date | week |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | WS - Jan 31 |
| 2022-02-02 | WS - Jan 31 |
| 2022-02-07 | WS - Feb 07 |
| 2022-02-08 | WS - Feb 07 |

What I have right now:

This gives a number of day of the week back as integer for calculation.

```
SELECT create_date, to_char(create_date, 'ID')::integer as dow
FROM customer;
```

I also figured how to produce a string.

```
SELECT create_date, to_char(create_date, '"WB - " Mon DD')
FROM customer;
```

What I don't know how to mange to get as result the first day of week for Monday to Friday like "WS - Jan 31"?

I also figured how to calculate first day of week as date but how put it in this result?

```
SELECT create_date - to_char(create_date, 'ID')::integer + 1
FROM customer;
```

I appreciate every help, I'm still into learning SQL from scratch and it's my first week of doing this at my new position.

Comment: Your code uses the prefix `WB` but your sample data shows `WS` - is that dynamic? If yes what is the rule to chose one prefix over the other?

Answer (score 0):

To get the start of the week from a `DATE` value, use `date_trunct()` the result can then be formatted using `to_char()`

```
to_char(date_trunc('week', create_date), 'Mon DD')
```

You can concatenate any prefix you want to the result of that, e.g.

```
concat('WS - ', to_char(date_trunc('week', create_date), 'Mon DD'))
```

Comment: With your answer i found a solution 
`SELECT
to_char(date_trunc('week', create_date), '"WB - " Mon DD')
FROM 
customer;
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `WS` is week starting , and `WB` is week beginning, so no real issue, try this:

```
WITH
indata(dt,wk) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2022-02-01','WS - Jan 31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-02','WS - Jan 31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-03','WS - Jan 31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-04','WS - Jan 31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-05','WS - Jan 31'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-07','WS - Feb 07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-08','WS - Feb 07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-09','WS - Feb 07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-10','WS - Feb 07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-11','WS - Feb 07'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2022-02-12','WS - Feb 07'
)
SELECT
  *
, EXTRACT(DOW FROM dt)
, 'WS - ' || TO_CHAR(dt - EXTRACT(DOW FROM dt)  + 2, 'Mon DD') AS wk_calc
FROM indata
ORDER BY 1;
-- out      dt     |     wk      | date_part |   wk_calc   
-- out ------------+-------------+-----------+-------------
-- out  2022-02-01 | WS - Jan 31 |         2 | WS - Feb 01
-- out  2022-02-02 | WS - Jan 31 |         3 | WS - Feb 01
-- out  2022-02-03 | WS - Jan 31 |         4 | WS - Feb 01
-- out  2022-02-04 | WS - Jan 31 |         5 | WS - Feb 01
-- out  2022-02-05 | WS - Jan 31 |         6 | WS - Feb 01
-- out  2022-02-07 | WS - Feb 07 |         1 | WS - Feb 08
-- out  2022-02-08 | WS - Feb 07 |         2 | WS - Feb 08
-- out  2022-02-09 | WS - Feb 07 |         3 | WS - Feb 08
-- out  2022-02-10 | WS - Feb 07 |         4 | WS - Feb 08
-- out  2022-02-11 | WS - Feb 07 |         5 | WS - Feb 08
-- out  2022-02-12 | WS - Feb 07 |         6 | WS - Feb 08
-- out (11 rows)
```